# Excel: Matching Column B with Column A and placing Identifier in Corresponding Column C,D,E,etc

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I have a list of names with their direct supervisor that I am trying to expand upon by showing the employees the next few layers down that work for the list of names.

Column C of the linked image brings back results of 1-7 by matching the list of names in A to those in the top row. This shows that "JR" works for "BE" but that "BE" works for "JW" so "JR" is technically under "JW" too.  What I am hoping to accomplish is to have a result similar to that shown below.

```
                Superv.    Employ.
               Column A   Column B   Column C   Column D   Column E
```

Names to Look for:    BE         JW         AD

```
                  BE         JR          1         2          3
                  BE         WP          1         2          3
                  JW         BE          2         3
                  AD         JW          3
                  JW         JH          2         3
                  AD         AD          3
```

These results would then be used to create lists of employees under a certain person.

Names to Look for:   BE          AD         JW

Employees            WP          JW         BE
                     JR          BE         WP
                                 JH         JR
                                 WP
                                 JR

Of course if there is another way to achieve the final result that would be easier then I wouldn't mind an altered format to what I currently have. If anyone has an idea how to achieve this please respond. Thanks

Comment: It looks like you require VBA with a reiterative loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little change to the output would make this easy:

In C2 put:

```
=A2
```

And copy down, this is the immediate supervisor.

Then in D2 we put:

```
=IFERROR(IF(C2=INDEX($A:$A,MATCH(C2,$B:$B,0)),"",INDEX($A:$A,MATCH(C2,$B:$B,0))),"")
```

Copy over and down till only empty cells appear:

[image]

This will return the name and not a number.

---

To get a number we can add a simple table that would denote the supervisor number:

[image]

Then we change the formulas to these:

In C2:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,I:J,2,FALSE)
```

Copy down.

In D2:

```
=IFERROR(IF(C2=VLOOKUP(INDEX($A:$A,MATCH(INDEX($I:$I,MATCH(C2,$J:$J,0)),$B:$B,0)),$I:$J,2,FALSE),"",VLOOKUP(INDEX($A:$A,MATCH(INDEX($I:$I,MATCH(C2,$J:$J,0)),$B:$B,0)),$I:$J,2,FALSE)),"")
```

copy down and over.

[image]

Comment: Applying your solution worked for the sample I made but I failed to provide you with some information that seems to have been critical for a solution so I appologize. In the table this would apply to it has names in the payroll section "column A" with the employees "column B" that are not in the list provided in your solutions columns I & J.

Comment: I can only answer what you asked.  Any inability to convert it to actual data is not the fault of the person who answered a flawed question.  The best would be to mark this as answered as it answered your question by clicking on the check mark by the answer. Then open a new question with the new requirements and what you have tried to do to adapt this to your real life data.  It is always better to offer more information then less. @Jrussell

Comment: It is causing columns D to show blanks or incorrect numbers when it comes to 1 specific name/number combo and only blanks for columns E through the rest. I can try to elaborate further if needed. Thank you

Comment: Without seeing your actual data it is hard to tell you what is going wrong.  I can only go by the data you showed.

Comment: I understand and I appreciate the help you have provided. I am working on a reformed question to include this new information.